# Java Object Serialization to JSON using Jackson

Tags: java, android, json, serialization, jackson

I have the following POJO classes

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class GroupUser {

@JsonProperty("userId")
int userId;
@JsonProperty("status")
int status;
@JsonProperty("admin")
int isAdmin;
@JsonProperty("email")
String email;
@JsonProperty("creator")
int Creator;
@JsonProperty("new")
int isNew;

// generated and cached
@JsonProperty("user_name")
String userName;

public GroupUser() {

}

@JsonIgnore
public GroupUser(String email, int isCreator) {
    this.userId = 0;
    this.email = email;
    this.Creator = isCreator;
    this.isAdmin = isCreator;

    if (isCreator == 1) {
        this.status = Group.STATE_ACCEPTED;
        this.isNew = 0;
    } else {
        this.isNew = 1;
        this.status = Group.STATE_INVITED;
    }
}

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

public int getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(int userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

public int getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(int status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public int getIsAdmin() {
    return isAdmin;
}

public void setIsAdmin(int isAdmin) {
    this.isAdmin = isAdmin;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public int getCreator() {
    return Creator;
}

public void setCreator(int creator) {
    Creator = creator;
}

public int getIsNew() {
    return isNew;
}

public void setIsNew(int isNew) {
    this.isNew = isNew;
}
}
```

And

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Group {

@JsonIgnore
final public static int STATE_INVITED = 1;
@JsonIgnore
final public static int STATE_REJECTED = 2;
@JsonIgnore
final public static int STATE_ACCEPTED = 3;
@JsonIgnore
final public static int STATE_PENDING = 4;

@JsonProperty("location")
String location;
@JsonProperty("radius")
int radius;
@JsonProperty("adminApprovalForObservers")
int isAdminApprovalRequired;
@JsonProperty("title")
String Title;
@JsonProperty("groupUsers")
GroupUser[] Users;
@JsonProperty("newVotingOnlyByAdmin")
int onlyAdminCreatesVote;
@JsonProperty("new")
int isNew;
@JsonProperty("requiredVotes")
int requiredVotes;
@JsonProperty("type")
int type;
@JsonProperty("allowObservers")
int allowObservers;
@JsonProperty("thumb")
String imageUrl;
@JsonProperty("timestamp")
long timeStamp;
@JsonProperty("openForAnyone")
int isOpenForAnyone;
@JsonProperty("uniqueId")
String uiqueId;
@JsonProperty("newDecisionOnlyByAdmin")
int newDecisionOnlyByAdmin;
@JsonProperty("requirePresence")
int requirePresence;
@JsonProperty("groupId")
int groupId;
@JsonProperty("automaticExclusions")
int autoExclusion;
@JsonProperty("adminApprovalForMembership")
int adminApprovalForMembership;
@JsonProperty("description")
String description;

// generated and cached
@JsonProperty("creator_name")
String creatorName;

public Group() {

}

@JsonIgnore
public Group(int id) {
    this.groupId = id;
}

@JsonIgnore
public Group(String name, String description, String imagePath) {
    this.Title = name;
    this.description = description;
    this.groupId = 0;
    this.location = "";
    this.radius = 0;
    this.imageUrl = imagePath;
    this.isNew = 1;
    this.Users = new GroupUser[] {};
    this.isOpenForAnyone = 1;
    this.onlyAdminCreatesVote = 0;
    this.adminApprovalForMembership = 0;
    this.allowObservers = 1;
    this.timeStamp = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() / 1000;
}

@JsonIgnore
public String getCreatorsEmail() {
    for (GroupUser u : Users) {
        if (u.getCreator() == 1) {
            return u.getEmail();
        }
    }
    return null;
}

@JsonIgnore
public int getCreatorsId() {
    for (GroupUser u : Users) {
        if (u.getCreator() == 1) {
            return u.getUserId();
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

@JsonIgnore
public GroupUser getUser(int userId) {
    if (Users != null) {
        for (GroupUser gu : Users) {
            if (gu.getUserId() == userId) {
                return gu;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public String getCreatorName() {
    return creatorName;
}

public void setCreatorName(String creatorName) {
    this.creatorName = creatorName;
}

public String getLocation() {
    return location;
}

public void setLocation(String location) {
    this.location = location;
}

public int getRadius() {
    return radius;
}

public void setRadius(int radius) {
    this.radius = radius;
}

public int getIsAdminApprovalRequired() {
    return isAdminApprovalRequired;
}

public void setIsAdminApprovalRequired(int isAdminApprovalRequired) {
    this.isAdminApprovalRequired = isAdminApprovalRequired;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return Title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    Title = title;
}

@JsonProperty("groupUsers")
public GroupUser[] getUsers() {
    return Users;
}

@JsonProperty("groupUsers")
public void setUsers(GroupUser[] users) {
    Users = users;
}

public int getOnlyAdminCreatesVote() {
    return onlyAdminCreatesVote;
}

public void setOnlyAdminCreatesVote(int onlyAdminCreatesVote) {
    this.onlyAdminCreatesVote = onlyAdminCreatesVote;
}

public int getIsNew() {
    return isNew;
}

public void setIsNew(int isNew) {
    this.isNew = isNew;
}

public int getRequiredVotes() {
    return requiredVotes;
}

public void setRequiredVotes(int requiredVotes) {
    this.requiredVotes = requiredVotes;
}

public int getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(int type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public int getAllowObservers() {
    return allowObservers;
}

public void setAllowObservers(int allowObservers) {
    this.allowObservers = allowObservers;
}

public String getImageUrl() {
    return imageUrl;
}

public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
    this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
}

public long getTimeStamp() {
    return timeStamp;
}

public void setTimeStamp(long timeStamp) {
    this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
}

public int getIsOpenForAnyone() {
    return isOpenForAnyone;
}

public void setIsOpenForAnyone(int isOpenForAnyone) {
    this.isOpenForAnyone = isOpenForAnyone;
}

public String getUiqueId() {
    return uiqueId;
}

public void setUiqueId(String uiqueId) {
    this.uiqueId = uiqueId;
}

public int getNewDecisionOnlyByAdmin() {
    return newDecisionOnlyByAdmin;
}

public void setNewDecisionOnlyByAdmin(int newDecisionOnlyByAdmin) {
    this.newDecisionOnlyByAdmin = newDecisionOnlyByAdmin;
}

public int getRequirePresence() {
    return requirePresence;
}

public void setRequirePresence(int requirePresence) {
    this.requirePresence = requirePresence;
}

public int getGroupId() {
    return groupId;
}

public void setGroupId(int groupId) {
    this.groupId = groupId;
}

public int getAutoExclusion() {
    return autoExclusion;
}

public void setAutoExclusion(int autoExclusion) {
    this.autoExclusion = autoExclusion;
}

public int getAdminApprovalForMembership() {
    return adminApprovalForMembership;
}

public void setAdminApprovalForMembership(int adminApprovalForMembership) {
    this.adminApprovalForMembership = adminApprovalForMembership;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}
}
```

I am using jackson library to serialize the `Group` Object to JSON like below:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_EMPTY_JSON_ARRAYS, true);

return mapper.writeValueAsString(group);
```

But the `Users` fields never gets serialized, no matter what `groupUsers` always is an empty array `[]`. Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you using setter to set any value for group user? If not then its initialised as empty array which is what you are seeing.

Comment: Yes I am setting value before serializing and have also tested writing in a log message the array size before serializing. even if the log shows the array size to be greater than 0 still the serialized json has an empty array.

Comment: Which version of `Jackson` are you using? I tested your `POJO` classes using version `2.4.1` and it works properly.

Comment: I am using 2.2, I'll try using 2.4.1 @MichałZiober